# Question about Ubiquiti Edgemax switch syntax and VLANs

Tags: switch, vlan, ubiquiti

I've been beating myself over the head with a keyboard trying to figure this out. I'm used to `switchport` syntax on Adtran and Cisco switches, but I've got this situation with a Ubiquiti EdgeSwitch 48 and a Mikrotik router that confuses me. What I want to do is have 4 VLANs, 4 ports are on the router, so for port config, just have whatever ports be `access` and have one `trunk` port for the uplink to the router for the internet. Basically, it's like dividing the ports on the switch into 4 parts and having separate networks for each part of the switch; literally the definition of a VLAN.

However, these (horrible, I might add) switches do not have trunk ports or switchport syntax. They have tagging and untagged ports. I read elsewhere that a tagged port is a trunk port in `switchport` syntax, but it doesn't seem to be working that way in my testing as I can still ping between 2 VLANs. Can someone explain what I can do if I want port 2 to be an uplink and port 3 to be a device on that VLAN?

Comment: Can't you simply configure a VLAN as untagged on an access port and each VLAN as tagged on the trunk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure what Cisco calls an access port, set the desired VLAN untagged on that port. For example, to have port 3 as an access port on VLAN 100, set VLAN 100 to untagged on port 3.

To create a trunk port, set the VLAN you want to be native as untagged on the port (port 2).  Set the other VLANs you want on the trunk as tagged on the port.